# how to fix the headers in a cv

Tags: header-footer

This is the begining of the cv that i want to do , but i've some problems with headers. this my mininal source code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}  
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{ 

\begin{flushleft}
 \textbf{blabla blabla}
 avenue of blabla, 30020 \\
 new blabla, blabla \\
 +00 00 00 00 00 \\
 blabla@blabla.blabla \\
\end{flushleft}  
\vfill
\begin{flushright}
  \includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=4cm]{blabla}
 \end{flushright}

\centering{\textsc{\huge BLABLA BLABLA\\ 
   \Large blabla blabla blabla  \\
   at blalblabla \\}}
\begin{flushleft}
  \section*{Formation}
  \vspace{-0.5cm}
  \titlerule
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{13cm}}
    2011-Aujourd'hui & -blablablabla  \\
    & \footnotesize{ school of blablablablabala}\\
    Été 2013 & again blablablaba \\ 
    2009-2011 & and again blabalblablal  \\
    2009 & -and again again blablablalba  \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
 }


 \begin{document}
 \null
 \end{document}
```

And i want to know how to fix the headers to become aligned without using \hspace and vspace and also i want to know how to put the sections in the document not in the ohead and also i want to know how to rule the section like the same example without using the \vspace, i want it automatically and thanks a lot for your help , i really appreciated .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Before proceeding any further, please consider whether jamming that much information into your header is advisable. I think it is redundant: everyone reading a CV knows that the address in a CV will be found on the first page; and the same is true of one's *formation*: no training is so amazing it merits mentioning more than once. More generally: a `\section` in a header does not make sense except in the most esoteric of documents. My advice for headers/footers is to include only the following: name, page number (maybe total page number), & the word 'CV'. All else belongs in the main text.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will get you started.  As I suggested in the comment, I'd keep virtually everything in the main part of the document and out of the headers.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\parindent 0pt            % <-- don't indent paragraphs?

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}

% Headers / Footers
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{My Name, CV}
\cfoot{\thepage}

% Sectional Divisions
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% <-- don't number sections, etc.
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\sffamily}
{\thesection}{.5em}{\bfseries}[\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{5cm}
  \includegraphics[width=3.5cm, height=4cm]{blabla}
\end{wrapfigure}
\textbf{blabla blabla}\\
avenue of blabla, 30020 \\
new blabla, blabla \\
+00 00 00 00 00 \\
blabla@blabla.blabla


\vspace{5\baselineskip}% <-- due to large 'demo' image
\section{Formation}

\begin{tabular}{@{} r | p{13cm}}
  2011-Aujourd'hui & -blablablabla  \\
  & {\footnotesize School of blablablablabala}\\
  Été 2013 & again blablablaba \\
  2009-2011 & and again blabalblablal  \\
  2009 & -and again again blablablalba  \\
\end{tabular}


\section{Etc.}

Et une autre chose\ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: tanks a lot for your help :)